# Programmatically determine the height of a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the height of a div, then position it based on the height. I've read various articles on this, but I always seem to be getting NaN as a result. Yes the javascript is loaded at the end of the body, after the divs are drawn.

I'm using asp.net to create this javascript dynamically. What I have output so far is:

```
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
var resultsInnerDiv = document.getElementById('resultsInnerDiv');
resultsInnerDiv.innerHTML = "test";
var h = parseInt(resultsInnerDiv.style.offsetHeight);
alert(parseInt(resultsInnerDiv.style.offsetHeight));
resultsInnerDiv.style.top = ((h / 2) -125) + 'px';
```

I need to get the actual height, instead of `NaN`. `NaN` pixels is obviously not valid.

Comment: jscript is not quite the same as javascript. Are you sure you don't mean the latter?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you had posted an executable code in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com.

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh you forgot two very important words: "as well"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this what you need:

```
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
var resultsInnerDiv = document.getElementById('resultsInnerDiv');
resultsInnerDiv.innerHTML = "test";
var h = parseInt(resultsInnerDiv.offsetHeight);
alert(parseInt(resultsInnerDiv.offsetHeight));
resultsInnerDiv.style.top = ((h / 2) -125) + 'px';
```

`offsetHeight` is not a property of `element.style`, but the element itself (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.offsetHeight)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
var resultsInnerDiv = document.getElementById('resultsInnerDiv');

resultsInnerDiv.innerHTML = "test";

var h = parseInt(resultsInnerDiv.offsetHeight);

alert(h);

resultsInnerDiv.style.top = ((h / 2) -125) + 'px';
```